# Python App executable created with autopytoexe, getting FileNotFoundError Win Errror 2 the system can not find the specified file

Tags: python, batch-file, pyinstaller

I have created an application with python using PYQT5, it all works flawlessly, I would like to be able to distribute it, to any system, so I started using pyinstaller and autopytoexe for this, However once the executable is created I get:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

I am using the subprocess module to run a batch file, which works flawlessly in my development setup.

When the .exe is created as soon as I try to run the batch file it crashes as it does not find the .bat file.

Also the window Icon does not show, although the executable Icon is set properly.

I have tried the following with autopytoexe, Have also tried the onfile option with the same resuts.

`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --icon "C:/Users/Myuser/Documents/Programming/Python/MyApp/img/MyIcon.ico" --add-data "C:/Users/Myuser/Documents/Programming/Python/MyApp/Bat/Programming.bat;Programming.bat" --add-data "C:/Users/Myuser/Documents/Programming/Python/MyApp/img/MyIcon.ico;MyIcon.ico"  "C:/Users/Myuser/Documents/Programming/Python/MyApp/Programmer.py"`

Am I missing anything in my setup ?

Has anyone else had this issue ?

Is there another way to add files to the application so that they get bundled to the .exe ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand what a *current working directory* is?

Comment: I understand what it is, But still do not know how to get the executable to find the files used in my application.

Answer (score 0):

The solution may have been too obvious for some people however it does not hurt to post the answer, The application was not finding the related files .bat and the icon because I was not targeting the files properly, after  some testing I found that the files should have been included like this:

```
--add-data "File path where the files are hosted ; Directory name where the files would be taken from at run time.  "
```